# BootCamp drivers - lost my Mac OSX CD

Tags: drivers, boot-camp

I've lost my Mac OSX Snow Leopard CD.

Where can I find BootCamp drivers and the latest driver-updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the official Apple site?
http://support.apple.com/downloads/#boot%20camp

Comment: There you can only get the updates, can't you?

Comment: @Svish correct, to my knowledge.

Comment: http://thepiratebay.org/torrent/3860505/BootCamp_2.0_(Leopard)_Windows_drivers | http://thepiratebay.org/torrent/5575916/BootCamp_3.1 | http://thepiratebay.org/torrent/5054638/Bootcamp_Driver_3.0_for_Windows_32bit__amp__64bit_(from_Snow_Leopard ... < In my opinion if one got the license, it doesn't matter how he obtains the given software. And if one talks about upload...whats the problem if I help for others who also lost it? :)

Comment: Please be careful about The Pirate Bay (or any other such site), there is no guarantee that the files are not "infected".

Comment: True. Try VirusTotal or scanning it with a live Disc, check comments ALWAYS. (Install an Avast Free! on the bootcamp, set it to high prior and start.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the "updates" have ALL the drivers. I'm 200% sure, in fact. There's no need to torrent it.

Answer (score 1):

After losing my own disk, I was completely unable to find a simple download from anywhere on the internet.

If you don't have a friend from whom you can borrow a copy of the disk, then under the assumption that you have bought the software or are otherwise *legally licensed to possess a copy*, I'd suggest you look into "alternate" methods of obtaining a copy or image of the disk.

(On a side note, I'm not sure if this kind answer is allowed on SuperUser, as I could find nothing in the FAQ or the meta site. I'm not by any means suggesting that you use any piece of software illegally, regardless of the perceived morality. I figure you'll either stay within the law, or you weren't going to in the first place. If a mod wants to clarify on this, please comment.)

Comment: I can confirm that you can find the drivers on the more shady places of the internet.