# Copying drivers from another Windows installation

Tags: windows, drivers, boot-camp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [BootCamp drivers - lost my Mac OSX CD](https://superuser.com/questions/154902/bootcamp-drivers-lost-my-mac-osx-cd)

Is it possible to copy the drivers from another Windows installation? I have re-installed my computer only to find that none of the drivers are installed. I have the disk from a previous installation which had the required drivers. Is it possible to copy these drivers across?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually get all the bootcamp drivers right from Apple. Although it says "Update", it appears that the update actually includes everything that's on the disk. Just grab it off off the [Boot Camp Support page.](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#boot%20camp)

Copying the drivers will not work - the files are usually spread around, along with registry stuff. So your best bet is to nab them off the internet from a manufacturer.

Comment: @JackWilsdon Try this one also then, it claims to not require a previous installation. http://support.apple.com/kb/DL830

Comment: @JackWilsdon yeah, thats what i was going to suggest next :P

Comment: Very unfortunate. You definitely should be able to get them somewhere... i find it odd.

Answer (score 4):

You can not simply install drivers by copying the files. Installation of a driver involves lots of more complicated steps than just copying files such as creating registry entries, services, event logs, and so on. Simply copying a file tells Windows nothing about the driver.

What you *can* do, is to copy the individual files as necessary (for example in the dialog below that prompts you for the location of a driver file). That said, the necessary files may not all be in the same place (`%systemroot%\System32\Drivers), and could be in the`Program Files`folder,`%systemroot%\Help`, and basically anywhere else the manufacturer thought its files belonged.

It is best just to use a copy of the original driver installation program, but if you don’t have Internet access or the CD, then maybe a copy of the driver installer has been cached. Look for an executable (`.exe`) or Windows Installer file (`.msi`) in the relevant `Program Files` folder and `\Windows\Installer` (perhaps do a file-search depending on the device manufacturer’s name).

[image]